# Using Spring 4.0's new ListenableFuture With Callbacks - Odd Results

Tags: java, spring, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

I have a web app that takes an array of IDs, queries an external webservice for each ID one at a time and publish each result as it arrives to a WebSocket client via a STOMP broker.  I can get this to work using simple Futures, but I'm trying to use Spring 4's new ListenableFutures and provide a callback.

The working code uses a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor that is defined in my root config.  I have a class called "SosQuery" with a method called "test" that is annotated with @Async and returns an AsyncResult.  Here is my working code being called from a root context service class:

```
@Override
    public void test(String[] oids) throws Exception {
        List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();

        for (String oid : oids) {
            futures.add(sosQuery.test(oid));
        }

        while (!futures.isEmpty()) {
            List<Future<String>> done = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
            for (Future<String> future : futures) {
                if (future.isDone()) {
                    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("me", "/queue/observation", future.get());
                    done.add(future);
                }
            }
            futures.removeAll(done);
        }
    }
```

This works fine and I see the responses arriving in my client.  I modified the SosQuery method that is defined with the @Async annotation to simply return "String", and created a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor in my root config.  Here is the modified method to use ListenableFuture:

```
 @Override
    public void test(String[] oids) throws Exception {
        for (final String oid : oids) {
              ListenableFuture<String> task = asyncTaskExecutor.submitListenable(new Callable<String>(){
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    String result = sosQuery.test(oid);
                    logger.debug("result for sosQuery: " + result);
                    return result;
                }
            });

            task.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result){
                    if (result == null){
                        result = "ITS NULL";
                    }
                    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("me", "/queue/observation", result);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t){
                    logger.error("Error executing callback.", t);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm seeing weird behavior... when I deploy in debug mode, I can see that the call() method is being executed and the result is being built from the SosQuery class properly, however my logger statement never appears in the logs.  Immediately aftewards, the onSuccess method executes, but the result String is null.

The onFailure method never gets called and there is absolutely nothing distinctive in the logs.  Documentation for using the ListableFutures is scarce and tightly coupled to the AsyncRestTemplate, but little exists for just creating your own tasks.  Does anybody have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you still have @Async in SosQuery.test method ?

Comment: Yes I do.  I'm not sure how debugging should actually go with so many threads, however I did just notice a couple of things: the result from the sosQuery.test(oid) method is returning before any sosQuery breakpoint gets hit, and the result String is null there. The next breakpoint that gets hit is the callback onSuccess. So the onSuccess is getting called before it's done?  After those breakpoints get hit several times, then my actual SosQuery.test breakpoints start getting hit.  Hmm...

Comment: You should remove @Async. Since you are already in thread you dont need to . If you remove Async everything will work with your current one. In your previous code you are creating seperate thread by adding Async but here but submitting new callable Spring would create new one automaticaly. So you dont need to have.

Comment: Ha!  Thanks Mani :)  Please add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct!

Comment: Oh ya, just a side note... this is totally not important to me, but for my test, I'm submitting a sequence of numbers 1-50.  If the ID is 41 I sleep for 3 seconds.  If the ID is 30 I sleep for 4 seconds. In my original code, I would see all the responses come back in order, minus 30 and 41, then 41 would come through, then 30 would come through.  Using the new code, they come back in a pretty crazy order: 1, 6, 15, 7, 2, 17, etc.  Just an interesting observation for whoever stumbles across this post.

Comment: IMHO Order is based on completion of the Job. In previous code you are checking in order thats why you are seeing the results in order, but in new one you are getting call back as soon as your job done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove @Async in your SosQuery.test method.

```
ListenableFuture<String> task = asyncTaskExecutor.submitListenable(new Callable<String>(){
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    String result = sosQuery.test(oid);
                    logger.debug("result for sosQuery: " + result);
                    return result;
                }
            });
```

Here the content inside the call() method is already invoked in separate thread . if you have @Async in test method. then it would create another thread and return immediately( that why you are getting response immediately before the test method completes)

And another important note from **[Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html#submitListenable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-)** **

```
    This implementation does not reuse threads! Consider a thread-pooling TaskExecutor 
implementation instead, in particular for executing a large number of short-lived tasks.
```